# Declaring a new method on a prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to declare a new method for a string that I have named 'shout'. I want it to change any string to the string in all capital letters with 5 exclamation points at the end. This code works, but only on the specific string that I have used in my if statement.

```
String.prototype.shout = function() {
    if('string' === 'string') {
         console.log('string!!!!!'.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `if ('string' === 'string')` supposed to be doing? That's always true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reference the 'this' object in your code:

```
String.prototype.shout = function() {
    return this.toUpperCase() + '!!!!!';
}
```

using 'this' will make it work on whatever is to the left of the dot (.) at call time

```
yourString.shout() // works on your string!
```

working jsBIN: https://jsbin.com/jepayu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

(Emphasis mine)

> I want it to *change* any string to the string in all capital letters with 5 exclamation points at the end.

Strings are immutable in Javascript. You can't change them. You can make a new one and return it.

```
String.prototype.shout = function () {
    return this.toUpperCase() + '!!!!!';
};

console.log('hello'.shout());
```